# How to use offsetTop relative to the body, when postion:relative prevents it?

Tags: javascript

So I know that without a positioned ancestor, .offsetTop is measured from the top of the  element.

I am trying to to slide in elements when they are half shown with JavaScript.

So the Javascript code calculates how far the image is from the top of the window and if the image is half shown, a CSS class is applied to the element.

But, since the parent element of the image (footer) is set to position:relative the offsetTop doesn't work anymore.

The code looks like this

```
const slideInAt = (window.scrollY + window.innerHeight) - sliderImage.height / 2;
const imageBottom = sliderImage.offsetTop + sliderImage.height;   
const isHalfShown = slideInAt > sliderImage.offsetTop;   
const isNotScrolledPast = window.scrollY < imageBottom;  

if (isHalfShown && isNotScrolledPast) {
  sliderImage.classList.add('active');
} else {
  sliderImage.classList.remove('active');
}
```

Here is the real life example: https://bluishbanana.github.io/

Any ideas how to solve that?

Answer (score 0):

There are two options here. First, and most straightforward, is getting rid of `offsetTop` for exact reasons you mentioned: it works with *relative* offsets, so is not really helpful when the parent is scrolled as well. To fetch absolute numbers, use [getBoundingClientRect()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getBoundingClientRect):

> The Element.getBoundingClientRect() method returns the size of an
> element and its position **relative to the viewport**.

The downside of this approach is its performance: even though you have this function as a scroll handler debounced, it's still not ideal to run the wrapper at each scroll.

An alternative is using [IntersectionObserver API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/IntersectionObserver/IntersectionObserver), which in 2021 has more-or-less adequate [browser support](https://caniuse.com/intersectionobserver):

> API that can be used to understand the visibility and position of DOM
> elements relative to a containing element or to the top-level
> viewport. The position is delivered asynchronously and is useful for
> understanding the visibility of elements and implementing pre-loading
> and deferred loading of DOM content.

With this approach, you won't have to debounce your handler, so both performance should be improved and not-so-subtle bugs also should be fixed.

Comment: Thanks a lot! But for the IntersectionObserver, if an element is positioned 100% to the left (margin-left="-100%"), the IntersectionObserver won't work, right? Since it is not visible.

Comment: That's an interesting question. Theoretically, there's an option of changing the 'container' element with `root` option, and using that root instead of viewport (so, for example, you might have another container for those images also left-moved offscreen). Didn't try it yet though; also support for root is less common.

Comment: alright, again thanks a lot for your help! One last question, in my example I would use getBoundingClientRect() like this: const imageBottom = sliderImage.getBoundingClientRect() + sliderImage.height;, right?

Comment: No, you actually can query bottom Y coordinate directly. Check the docs for details.